# Scala & json4s - parsing JSON with fields that start with a numeric character

Tags: json, scala, parsing, json4s

I've got deeply nested JSON parsers (using `json4s.jackson`) that I'm trying to simplify using case classes.

My problem is...  some of the fields start with numbers, but scala cannot have an arg name that starts with a numeric character.

Example:

```
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s._

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

val jsonStr = """{"5gLog":{"i":99}}"""      // <--- note the field "5gLog"
val jval = parse(jsonStr)

case class Raw5gLog(i: Int)
val raw5gLog = (jval \ "5gLog").extract[Raw5gLog]
```

This works.  But what I need to do, because these fields are nested deep within the JSON...  is something like this...

```
val jsonStr = """{"xgLog":{"i":99}}"""
val jval = parse(jsonStr)

case class RawRecord(xgLog: Raw5gLog)
val rawRecord = jval.extract[RawRecord]
```

This would work...  if the fields were named like `xgLog`, but the fields are actually named like `5gLog` as above, and I can't give an arg name to a class like `5gLog`...

```
case class RawRecord(5gLog: Raw5gLog)
// error: Invalid literal number
```

I thought about something like

```
parse(jsonStr.replace("\"5g", "\"fiveg"))
```

But there's real data, beyond the field names, in the JSON that can be impacted.

The best solution I can figure is to add extra apply methods to the affected case classes...

```
case class RawRecord(fivegLog: Raw5gLog)

object RawRecord {
  def apply(jval: JValue): RawRecord =
    RawRecord( (jval \ "5gLog").extract[Raw5gLog] )
}

val rawRecord = RawRecord(jval)
```

But I feel like every time I make some structurally different workaround like this for an edge case, it's always the beginning of my code turning into a mess.  I could give every case class a new apply method and use it for everything, but it seems like a lot of extra code for a small subset of the data.

Is there a better way?

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala can use any string as a variable name, but you may have to quote it with backticks:

```
case class RawRecord(`5gLog`: Raw5gLog)
```

You also need to do this if you have a field called `type` or any other reserved word. This is how `-` can be a function name, for example.